# How to implement 2-way communication between Lex and a user through text messaging without using AWS Pinpoint or Twilio

Tags: sms, amazon-lex

I have a Lex bot that I need to implement a way to talk to through SMS. I was asked to try and make it work using Amazon SNS.

I understand that Amazon SNS is a notification service. It seems simple to send messages from Lex as they did in [this tutorial](https://2sherpas.github.io/chatbot-using-aws-lex-lambda-and-sns). However, it is my understanding that AWS SNS doesn't save sessions, which some of my Lex intents require. I'm also not sure how SNS can receive messages from the user.

Is there a way I can have 2-way communication between the Lex and user through text messaging? Ideally using Amazon SNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Pinpoint is probably the solution you're looking for in this scenario.

Pinpoint supports two-way SMS with integration into the rest of the Amazon stack; including Lex.

[Here's the link to the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-sms-two-way.html) and [here is a tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs//messaging-and-targeting/create-an-sms-chatbox-with-amazon-pinpoint-and-lex/) that will help guide you along the way.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So just clarifying, Pinpoint is the only AWS service that lets us have two-way communication between a bot and SMS?

Comment: As with anything in AWS, there are always multiple ways to build a solution. The approach I've suggested makes use of ready-to-go AWS services. You can, of course, choose to build out the solution from scratch.
An approach would be to use API Gateway to receive the inbound SMS messages from your MNO. Thereafter, drop the messages onto SNS for delivery to SQS. Attach a trigger to SQS to deliver the message to a Lambda function. From there you will need custom logic to maintain state (match phone number to Lex session), invoke Lex and then send the appropriate SMS response.